# Fetch labels from a array using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

My table is as below -

**Table 1:**

```
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id |                                                              label_value |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | [{"label":"3500 - Application","value":"35060"},{"label":"3450 - Content","value":"34650"},{"label":"3890 - Mobile","value":"38960"}]   |
|  2 | [{"label":"3700 - Application","value":"3500"},{"label":"3950 - Content","value":"3450"},{"label":"3290 - Mobile","value":"3890"}]      |
|  3 | [{"label":"3540 - Application","value":"35400"},{"label":"3480 - Content","value":"34650"},{"label":"39090 - Mobile","value":"38390"}]  |
|  4 | [{"label":"350220 - Application","value":"3500"},{"label":"342250 - Content","value":"3450"},{"label":"38190 - Mobile","value":"3890"}] |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Table 2:**

```
+-----+----------------+-------+
| id  | table_1_ref_id | value |
+-----+----------------+-------+
|   1 |              1 | 35060 |
|   2 |              1 | 38960 |
|   3 |              1 | 35060 |
|   4 |              3 | 38390 |
|   5 |              2 |  3450 |
|   6 |              4 |  3890 |
+-----+----------------+-------+
```

I have two tables where one of the column stores data in the form of an array. This array stores values in the form of a **label-value** pair. So, I need to extract the label depending upon the value in that pair.

The other table stores the value mentioned in the array (In Table 2). Now, I have to find the associated **label** that is mentioned in Table 1 depending upon the value in Table 2.

For the above sample table, the output that I am expecting is as below -
**Expected Output**

```
3500 - Application
3890 - Mobile
3500 - Application
39090 - Mobile
3950 - Content
38190 - Mobile
```

How can I achieve the above output?

Comment: The question is unclear (at least I cannot understand it). I suspect that you need a different, normalized data model, otherwise your unhappiness will only increase.

Comment: I have re-phrased the question, can you please review it again?

Comment: Added the table using formatted text. The first table looks a bit cluttered but that might be because of the large data set in column 2.

Comment: I would do it like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c5d2dd4271fb2e0ef0cd1b7baa921f4a (until the question is re-opened, I can't add a proper answer)

Comment: Thanks for the help @a_horse_with_no_name
The suggested approach seems to work but I am receiving an error "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression".

Comment: @AyushAgrawal: then your JSON array contains more than one entry with the same `value`. You will need to use a `LIMIT` or make sure the values are unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two tables and then use `jsonb_array_elements` to iterate over the JSNO value and pick the one with the matching value:

Apparently you have multiple entries in the JSON array with the same `value`, so you need to apply a limit to the subselect.

```
select t1.id, 
       (select e ->> 'label'
        from jsonb_array_elements(t1.label_value) as x(e)
        where x.e ->> 'value' = t2.value::text
        limit 1) as label
from t1
  join t2 on t1.id = t2.table_1_ref_id;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c5a6af348b128ee4f71c17d3b5349566)

Comment: I tried going step-by-step so I tried the following (Using the above suggestion) -
 
select t1.id, 
       (select e ->> 'label'
        from jsonb_array_elements(t1.label_value) as x(e)
        limit 1) as label
from t1

I am receiving the error: cannot extract elements from an object

select t1.id, 
       (select e ->> 'label'
        from jsonb_array_elements(t1.label_value) as x(e)) as label
from t1

I am receiving the error: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

I have checked my database and I have no duplication.

Comment: Then apparently your real JSON structure doesn't match the one you included in your question. You can analyze the data in the online demo and compare it with your real data to find the difference. "More than one row returned" can always be fixed by adding `LIMIT 1` as I did in my answer